# How to create WPF window that will never gains focus

Tags: .net, wpf, winapi, keyboard, focus

I want to create WPF form that will never gains focus.
Windows keyboard has same behavior as I want to achieve.
[image: Windows keyboard]

If you will use this keyboard any other form will never lose focus.

[image: Form]

I tried to give focus back on activated event:

```
 wpfKeyboard.Activated += (o, e) =>
{
   // hack
    this.ActivatePreviousWindow();
};
```

But this is not correct behaviour (some events are terminated)

P.s. In test form "activate" "deactivate" events are not called. So windows keyboard does the trick without activation back...

Comment: `WS_EX_NOACTIVATE` is what the OSK uses. Although I don't know how to set window-creation flags for a WPF window, you can probably find out using Google.

Comment: Did the Googling for you. Once you know the right keywords, finding stuff is easy. :-)

Comment: @CodyGray thanks. The exactly what I am searching for.